# Set sendmail_path

Tags: php, sendmail

I've been using the sendmail_path to set the from address when a Bootstrap form is submitted. This is preferred over the server default of user@servername.com.

Recently several sites I've worked on have been upgraded to PHP 7.4. This newer version of PHP has broken the php.ini file function I had set.

Does anyone know how I might mod the code below to restore the previous functionality?

This code was working prior to PHP 7.4, but now returns user@servername.com instead of the address I have set.

```
sendmail_path="/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f noreply@thisdomain.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here.

1. Change the php.ini file
2. Use

```php
ini_set('sendmail_path', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f noreply@thisdomain.com');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it sorts of work with a caveat.  For some reason this sends 2 emails.

Email 1 - The "from address" is the email address I entered in the form.

Email 2 - the "from address" is user@servername.com

Comment: In case you are using the `mail` command, try
```php
$to = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: noreply@thisdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: noreply@thisdomain.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```
and remove the `-f noreply@thisdomain.com` from the `ini_set`

Comment: Ended up fixing this by modifying the PHP in formmail. Would have rather gone php.ini route since it's an easier fix, but could not get it not send 2 copies of every msg submitted.